# Azure SQL Search. Full-text search. Optimise select statement

Tags: sql-server, azure, full-text-search, fulltext-index

I got a table with around 20 millions of rows. 
The database is hosted on Azure. (S2 tier)
I set up full-text index on one of the columns (the column contains Counties, States, Cities, Towns, Townships, Villages, Schools, Colleges and so on).

Here is an example of select statement :

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.[Table_Name]
WHERE CONTAINS(Value,'"clair county" OR "alabama" OR "miami" OR "talladega county"
OR "jefferson county" OR "shelby county"  OR "colorado")
```

Whenever I launch on regular SQL Server (not azure) I get ~35k rows within 1 second. But on azure it takes around 6 minutes. The problem why it takes that much is because it hits DTU maximum. 
When this query executes it takes only around 1% of CPU usage and 100% of Data IO Usage (a lot of reads).
So I'd really like to optimise such kind of queries. Even on p11 pricing tier it is much slower than on regular SQL Server Developer Edition.

Here are several solutions I can think of:

1. Stop using SQL Azure and switch to Azure VM, where I can host regular SQL Server. I assume the problem when it hits limit of DTU due lots of read may be resolved
2. Optimise query. I assume there should be a way to create query that excludes around 95% of rows. Here is example of rows query specified above returns: `Jefferson Union High School District`, `Miami-Yoder School District 60-JT`, `Upper Saint Clair School District`, `Louisville/Jefferson County`. Maybe there is a way of creating query when SQL Server returns rows that contains words only among specific words, so I don't get `Jefferson Union High School District` since words `Union`, `High`, `School` are not specified in query.
3. Reorganise table in order to change number of reads. (Not sure if it possible)

Thanks

Comment: Well the problem was solved by reorganising database schema. It seems like there is no way to optimise a lot select agains full-text search.

Comment: Outside of Azure, performance can be optimized by moving the data files, log, and full text catalog to different drives optimized for reads or writes depending on the files. I've seen that make a considerable improvement. I don't know if Azure gives you these options though.